# Are transpiler languages allowed?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, languages

I recently created a simple little language that transpiles Brainfuck into a format that is half the size of its input. It can be used to compress and decompress Brainfuck programs.

Provided I include a link to the transpiler, am I allowed to use this transpiler language as a submission, or is this against the rules?

Comment: hint: Is Typescript allowed? Why or why not?

Comment: Probably okay given that [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) is allowed.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be? As an aside though, it doesn't really matter how long the brainfuck code is, as [tag:code-golf] questions are between languages. Honestly, you'll probably get less votes if you compress it into a shorter language anyway, and there's already dozens of brainfuck derivatives floating around

Comment: With a bit more work, you can probably achieve a 3/8 compression ratio, since brainfuck uses 2^3 characters out of 2^8 available.

Comment: @isaacg Would probably be possible. My compressor for now is limited to the ASCII range but if I go outside ASCII smaller compression will be possible.

Comment: Are you looking for CompressedFuck?

Comment: I mean technically, doesn't everything transpile to machine code anyway?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can - you do however have to make sure that it is clear what transpiler you used as well as the interpreter/compiler of the language you transpile into you use.

Comment: I have to say I think this should be conditional: you should only be allowed to use a transpiler if the transpiler is Turing-Complete within the restrictions of the language or something like that. I'm new so IDK how formal we want to be, but I feel a simple "single character creates entire program" transpiler would be abused. Maybe only transpilers existing before the question was created are allowed? @flawr

Comment: @mackycheese21 The same question arose with the golfing languages people created. For some time we had the rule that the language (which we say is specified by a specific interpreter) must have existed before the corresponding challenge was posted. But then we moved away from this rule and these kind of boring solutions that you mentioned never actually became a problem, so you rarely find anyone even trying it, and if so, they usually don't get a lot of attention.

Comment: Relevant links: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7560/may-i-create-my-own-programming-language-which-uses-an-existing-compiler https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1071#1071 https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-programming-language-should-we-consider-for-the-code-golf-solution/10#10