# Is Ctrl-C one keystroke or two?

Tags: discussion, policy, code-golf, answers

Preliminary question: is it valid to score Excel in keystrokes? I guess it is, but I'm not sure what our policy is.

Assuming it is (or, in general, for languages that are scored in keystrokes), does Ctrl-C count as one keystroke or two?

If it is two, would uppercase "A" be two keystrokes as well? Can for example be assumed that Caps-Lock is initially on?

In case some context is needed: [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111884/36398) is the answer that uses Ctrl-C in Excel and caused me to ask about this.

Comment: Well `shift+a` (i.e. capital A), is one byte or character, so that would be 1 byte. `^C` could be represented as control+C. or 0x03 ETX, meaning it depends on context

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42963) and the dupe link thereof.

Comment: @Downgoat The capital "A" characeter is indeed one byte (in most encodings). But my premise is that the language is being scored in keystrokes. So, how many keystrokes is capital "A"?

Comment: Yet another reason to just score everything by bytes...

Comment: @Mego That may be the case, but doesn't answer my question

Comment: @LuisMendo Hence why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I think we should ask this first- "Does modifiers (Shift, Ctrl, Alt, etc) count as one keystroke?"

Comment: I think scoring by keystrokes is not a valid way to score a submission (unless there's a meta post I don't know about).  Since you are coming up with a different scoring method, I'm not sure why the number of keystrokes matters.

Comment: @NathanMerrill I thought there was, but I can't find a meta post. My question didn't meant to come up with a new method. Rather, that method of scoring is used in the linked answer, so I just wanted to know if counting as a single keystroke was valid or not

Answer (score 5):

## One Keystroke

A key sequence such as Ctrl+C is the 'C' key event with a 'Ctrl' key modifier. It's one singular input to the computer. This reasoning is used in some programming languages including [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(java.lang.Character,%20int))

Comment: Yup. `^C` is 1 keystroke. It qualifies as one ascii byte. +1 :)