# Is Shortening Cell Addresses Valid?

Tags: discussion

In Excel, Excel VBA, and Google Sheets cell (and range) address may be redefined by the user as special `Named Range` objects, is the use of these objects allowed by default - that is, may it be assumed that cell `A1` is renamed to `A` and Cell `B1` is renamed to `b` by default such as is done in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150068/61846)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No, Unless done programmatically

It is invalid to assume that the user has manually redefined a given range to a shorter name. You may, however do so programmatically as part of your answer. An example of valid code renaming range `[A1]` to `[A]` in VBA is included below

```vb
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add"A","=A1"
```

Comment: Move your reason here

Comment: or if the bytecount is counted for the `.xls(x)` file, not just the formula. No one would want to that, however.

Comment: If use bytecount, lots of submissions would have the same size, for some alignment

Comment: @user202729 - the community has decidedly [voted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10141/61846) against that and instead decided to limit what counts as an Excel or similar language - part of which includes not allowing anything but keyboard input

Comment: @TaylorScott And you seems to misunderstood me - I meant measure the bytecount of the saved worksheet file. The file stored on hard disk. Of course no one want to do that.

Comment: @user202729 I understood what you meant, I was just pointing out that the community has voted against counting Excel, Minecraft, Google Sheets and several other languages' bytecounts in this manner

Answer (score -3):

## Yes.

When really using Excel formula, the source values are usually not in `A1` `A2` `B1` or anything. To make it clear we use name to mean the source. Thus if `A1` is allowed, `a` should

Comment: The problems that I see with this are two-fold: 1 - it *requires* user action that is neither self explanatory to someone who does not know these languages nor standardized, which leads to confusion in implementation and 2 - It corresponds to a distinct programmable action that you are bypassing without contributing anything to the bytecount

Comment: And believe me, I would benefit from this being a change - at the time of writing this, I have 230 answers written in Excel, Excel VBA and/or Google Sheets - but I feel strongly that this is does not operate within the spirit of code golf and would only serve to add confusion to these languages

Comment: For the `programable` it doesn't hurt, as long as you don't use `ROW` or anything that related to the position.

Comment: I just post the opinion, and do no vote here. I guess you voted

Comment: You should have a common standard on languages, not choose the longer one on each. For C or anything you are not allowed to assume value stored in variable `t`, and in Excel you shouldn't assume value stored in `A1`

Comment: while, yes in theory it would be nice to handle all languages the same, it is entirel impractical for a site that handles so may esolangs - for instance [Piet](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Piet), [Brainf**k](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), Minecraft, Chess, VBA - they are just so different that they can't be held to the same standards. This is the core reason why I have added so many answers to the [VBA Tips page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5175/tips-for-golfing-in-vba)

Comment: As for the "prior data" in a specified cell, that really not the intention, and in fact that interpretation would be disallowed as a [standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default); Rather specifying a cell within the formula is just the STDIN (standard input) for Excel and Excel VBA - you can think of it more as you first write the formula *then* you take the user input via those specified cells.

Comment: Further, cells in the range `A1`,`B1` ... are chosen as the defaults simply to simplify reading formulas in these languages, so if the problem statement species an ordered tuple of 2 arguments the reader may safely assume that `A1` represents the first element in the tuple and `B1` represents the second