# It seems the consensus on Scratch is to use scratchblocks2 syntax, but what about "when green flag clicked"?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, scoring

In many code-golf Scratch submissions, I see `when green flag clicked` used, when `when gf clicked` is also valid in scratchblocks2. Is there a reason for this, or is it just because people submit raw conversions?

Comment: The example in the [scratch scoring meta question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5013/76162) seems to use `when gf clicked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the code works (produces the expected output for the given input) in the implementation you are targetting, it is valid.